# GKE Windows Node, health check

Tags: gke-networking

I'm not used to posting things but I have a problem. On GKE, I set a service of type Loadbalancer for windows pods on windows nodes but the health check of the load balancer is KO for windows nodes. I can use externalTrafficPolicy: cluster but i need Local for my applications.

How to fix it ?

Thanks for your help.

Alexandre Gué,
Team leader Infra
PI ELECTRONIQUE

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the Health check [ranges](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#ip-ranges) for different Load Balancers?

> For health checks to work, you must create ingress allow firewall
> rules so that traffic from Google Cloud probers can connect to your
> backends.

A firewall rule should have created per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#fw-rule):

> The following example creates an ingress firewall rule for the
> following load balancers:

- Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing (health checks)
- Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing (health checks)
- TCP Proxy Load Balancing (health checks)
- SSL Proxy Load Balancing (health checks)
- HTTP(S) Load Balancing (health checks and legacy health checks)

> For these load balancers, the source
> IP ranges for health checks (including legacy health checks if used
> for HTTP(S) Load Balancing) are:
>
> 35.191.0.0/16
> 130.211.0.0/22

Also be aware of Windows Server Containers [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster-windows#limitations):

> There are some Kubernetes features that are not yet supported for
> Windows Server containers. In addition, some features are
> Linux-specific and do not work for Windows. For the complete list of
> supported and unsupported Kubernetes features, see the Kubernetes
> documentation.